# Change of job recently prior to applying UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-employment

I would like to know, if someone takes a new job within 3 months prior to applying for UK visit visa, is there any specific rule for that? I have browsed in Google but couldn't find appropriate answer. Please help me regarding this matter.

Comment: What type of visa ? And why do you think it will be a problem ?

Comment: Its a visit visa. My husband is going to change his job. He is planning to attend a convocation in the Uk in june. Bt he got a good job offer. So we were just thinking , changing job will be an issue or not.

Comment: From your previous questions it seems you have been refused visas to UK. If this is a way to get around it, it will not be much helpful. So prepare diligently before applying. Changing jobs isn't a big issue, people do it all the time. If you can provide documents to prove it all is fine.

Comment: @DumbCoder, your comment is a viable answer!  It's fine, and you are in a good position to provide it. Please consider promoting your comment.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur advice. My visa got rejected earlier in this year. I got it in the 2nd application. Now my husband is applying for the 1st time . We wish to make a good and relevant application so that it gets approved in the 1st attempt.thats y asked for your help.

Comment: @Farah: Be sure to fix your keyboard before you type up the application. It seems to be randomly dropping the first letters in words such as "you" and "why".

Answer (score 2):

As @DumbCoder mentioned, changing jobs is no big deal as people do it all the time. As long as you provide documents backing it up and all the necessary paperwork required for the visa you should be fine, just prepare well and make sure you have everything.